# Open 2 powerpoint applications(POWERPNT.EXE) separately

Tags: ms-office, office-interop

I am trying to Open 2 powerpoint applications(POWERPNT.EXE) separately. In Office 2013, 2 pptx file opens in 2 different windows but from the task manager we can see that it under only 1 application as in office 2007.
For Word and Excel, after making some registry editing under the key ***hkey_class_roots\Word.Document.12\shell\open***, command and ***ddeexec***, but the main key ie, ddeexec key is not available under powerpoint.slide.12.

In this [TASK MANAGER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqcxp.png) you can see, that there 2 different winword.exe, and excel.exe. Here one app among the 2, are opened by c# code. By C# code, the following are opened - Presentation1.pptx, Project Milestones, Composite_id.xlsx.

What things can be done in order to Open 2 powerpoint applications(POWERPNT.EXE) separately?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Andres.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you'd like to do this? Maybe you're just using the wrong approach to some problem.

Comment: Due to security reasons for some documents, the apps should be separate.

Comment: Anything speaking against launching an instance under a different user? Should provide even more isolation.

Comment: No different user, only one user(Non-admin only).